# Socket.io - Stop listening event client-side

Tags: socket.io

Im trying to stop listening to an event (Client-side) on socket.io, I'm using this to listen to the event:

```
    function connectWebSocket(channel){
        var socket = io('https://mywebsite.com:3000');
        socket.on('connect', () =>{
            console.log('connected');
            socket.on('test', function(data) {
               alert('event call');
            });
        });
    }
```

It works ok, but how i stop listening to the event 'test'?

I tried:

```
   socket.off('test');
```

also tried:

```
   socket.removeAllListeners('test);
```

and a lot of more commands, but nothing seems to work, as i started listening client-side, how i stop listening client-side?